# Django admin actions form that working

Tags: python, django

I have the code below. I have an action 'send_offer' in OfferAdmin.

Basically, the action displays a form that when people complete, an email to the user is sent.

However, the code below does not work for me. I see the form when I click on a checkbox beside an offer and select "Send offer email" from the drop down menu in the django admin, but the email to the user is not being sent.

Basically the part of the code below the line request.method == 'POST' is not working.

What should I do?

```
class OfferAdmin:
...

    class OfferForm(forms.Form):
        title = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
        image_link = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
        list_price = forms.FloatField()
        discount_price = forms.FloatField()
        exclusive_price = forms.FloatField()
        comments = forms.CharField(widget=forms.widgets.Textarea())

    def send_offer(self, request, queryset):
        form = None

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = self.OfferForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():

                for bid in queryset:
                    title = form.cleaned_data['title']
                    image_link = form.cleaned_data['image_link']
                    list_price = form.cleaned_data['list_price']
                    discount_price = form.cleaned_data['discount_price']
                    exclusive_price = form.cleaned_data['exclusive_price']
                    comments = form.cleaned_data['comments']

                    form_params = {
                        'title': title,
                        'image_link': image_link,
                        'list_price': list_price,
                        'discount_price': discount_price,
                        'exclusive_price': exclusive_price,
                        'comments': comments
                    }

                    params = {
                        'obj': bid,
                        'form': form_params
                    }

                    rts = render_to_string
                    subject = rts(
                        'shopper/email/email-offer-subject.txt', params)
                    text = rts('shopper/email/email-offer.txt', params)
                    html = rts('shopper/email/email-offer.html', params)
                    bid.user.send_email(subject, text, html)

                    self.message_user(request, "Successfully sent email")

                    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())

        if not form:
            for obj in queryset:
                data = {
                    'title': obj.product.title,
                    'image_link': obj.image_link,
                    'list_price': obj.list_price,
                    'discount_price': obj.discount_price,
                    'exclusive_price': obj.exclusive_price,
                }
            form = self.OfferForm(data)

    return render_to_response(
        "shopper/admin/offer_form.html", {
            'bids': queryset, 'offer_form': form},
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))

send_offer.short_description = "Send offer email"
```

Comment: `return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())` should be outside for loop.

It will be better to initialize `form_params` outside for loop because it's value is independent of queryset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [intermediate page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages) that will handle form submission.

As your code currenlty work, when form is submitted request is processed by changelist views and
not `send_offer` function.

EDIT: Also, please note that admin action always receive POST request.